# Projeto empty MVc. Não consigo startar

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Comecei a fazer um projeto do zero usando o MVC 4 do VS 2012. Como eu optei por um empty, não consigo fazer startar a view. Fiz a rota:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Operador",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Operador", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
```

Mas quando eu dou um F5, me dá esse erro:

```
Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.

Não é possível encontrar o recurso. 
  Descrição: HTTP 404. O recurso que você está procurando (ou uma de suas dependências) não pôde ser removido, seu nome foi alterado ou está temporariamente indisponível. Examine o URL e certifique-se de que está digitado corretamente. 

 URL solicitada: /


Informações sobre a Versão: Microsoft .NET Framework Versão:4.0.30319; Versão do ASP.NET:4.0.30319.34249
```

Na minha URL que é: `http://localhost:60975/` eu adiciono após a barra(/) o nome da controller e continua me dando erro que não encontrou a view Index. Como eu resolvo isso?

```
public class OperadorController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Operador/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Operador";
}

<h2>Operador</h2>
```

O Package.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AutoMapper" version="4.0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.6" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Global.asax

```
// Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
```

O Route.config

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Operador",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Operador", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
    }
}
```

Comment: `MeuController` existe?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, sim ele existe e criei uma view para ele. Só não estou sabendo é como chamá-lo.

Comment: Esquisito. Pode colocar o Controller e a View na sua pergunta, por favor?

Comment: Editei a pergunta

Comment: Pode colocar também o `packages.config` na pergunta? Aparentemente está tudo certo com a estrutura.

Comment: Também está ok. Quero verificar o `Global.asax.cs`, se possível.

Comment: Está tudo certo. Não sei mais o que poderia ser.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, eu clico com o botão direito em cima da minha Action e dou Go to View e me vem a seguinte mensagem: Unable to find matching view. Deletei a view e a refiz e continua a mesma coisa, ou seja, ele não está achando a view, agora não sei o porque.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sei que já respondeu sua própria pergunta, mas queria expandir um pouco mais. Como já percebeu, o MVC usa muito *convenções*. Porém, há meios de fazer fora das convenções e faz o que você quiser.

No seu caso, a convenção é que tem que ter um view com o *mesmo nome* que a ação que está no controller. Por exemplo:

*Controller.cs*

```
public ActionResult AlgumaCoisa()
{
  return View();
}
```

Assim, por convenção, teria que criar um view com o mesmo nome:

*AlgumaCoisa.cshtml*

```
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Alguma Coisa" }
<h2>Alguma coisa está aqui</h2>
```

É bom saber também que views que existem em outras pastas também pode ser usada:

*Controller.cs*

```
public ActionResult AlgumaOutraCoisa()
{
  return View("AlgumaCoisa/AlgumaOutraCoisa");
}
```

E seu view:

*/AlgumaCoisa/AlgumaOutraCoisa.cshtml*

```
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Alguma outra coisa." }
<h2>Alguma outra coisa está aqui.</h2>
```

Comment: brazilianldsjaguar, bom dia. Então, como eu criei um projeto empty, achei que ele fosse empty mesmo. Quando eu criei a controller, ele já criou uma action chamada Index(esqueleto apenas) e no Route.config, a mesma coisa. Acho que foi isso que estava acontecendo e você me respondeu muito bem, até marquei a sua resposta por ter mais consistência e explicação plausível. Entendi o que estava acontecendo.

Comment: Valeu! O MVC já me pegou algumas vezes também.

Answer (score 1):

Já sei o que houve. Não existe a view Index, logo ele quer retornar essa view. Fiz assim em minha controller e resolveu:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("Operador");
        }
```